# scope of questions in api.ai

Tags: bots, chatbot, dialogflow-es

Can anyone suggest me , how to allowed scope of questions in **api.ai**? i.e. I want to ask user "how many book can you carry at a time ?" : user can reply any positive integer number. Then my bot reply: "good , you can still better than others!". now, without any reference if user directly write "any positive integer number" at starting then also bot reply : "good , you can still better than others!" , instead of "I didn't get"(or default response.). This answer come only when previous question has been asked.How can I do this?

==== case : 1 ====
Bot: how many book can you carry at a time ?
User:5
Bot:good , you can still better than others!

=== case : 2 ===
(without any reference if users gives inputs at very starting of conversation)
User: 5
Bot: good , you can still better than others!

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Frankly, I'm not sure what do you mean. But I think you need to look into the input/output contexts if you want to carry state from one intent to another.

Comment: @BelaVizy what you can't understand ? Do you need more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a required parameter instead of putting numbers in `User says`:

In your intent configure your action to have one required parameter `numBooks`. Have the prompt for that parameter be "how many book can you carry at a time ?". Then for that intent, have the response be, "good , you can still better than others!". Finally, in the `User says` section, add anything you want the user to say to trigger the intent, for example: "hi". Save your intent. Now whenever a user says "hi" the bot will ask the question and the conversation will begin. But if the user randomly sends a number, it will respond with fallback intent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What to do if it is not at starting of conversation .i.e. I have to follow the previous answer and according to answer need to give response .(If user says in between conversation " need classic book ." Bot have to response only if registered user.Still in my case if I write anywhere above question it is giving this response.) I am very new for this.Also is there any "regex" available for api.ai.i.e. user can only purchase books up to two digits only(0 to 99).Now ,In my case user can enter any number of books to purchase and it is allowed by bot which is invalid.